# Can you change your gut microbiota by changing your diet? Would that affect calorie uptake?

Tags: microbiology, metabolism, diet, microbiome

I have seen peer-reviewed papers mentioning the daily changes in gut microbiota composition according to dietary changes. See for example this paper:

http://genomebiology.com/2014/15/7/R89

My question is related to this one:

[Relationship between our microbiome and personalized nutrition](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1999/relationship-between-our-microbiome-and-personalized-nutrition/2000#2000)

If, according to these recently published scientific results, it takes a day to change the gut microbiota to adjust to the dietary change, and the presence of certain microbes makes food assimilation more effective,

Does this mean that alternating a protein-rich meat and dairy diet with a carbs-rich diet every day would make our microbiota switch daily and not have time to increase calorie uptake?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it should be noted that a stable, healthy microbiome is generally thought to be a marker of health; actively disrupting it through diet in an attempt to fight with it over nutrients is therefore not necessarily a good idea, as it can affect the health of not only your gut but also your immune system, etc.

Dysfunctional microbiomes are for example [associated with behavioral problems](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30704642/) in eating disorders.

Nonetheless, [diet shifts have been used as a tool](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5385025/) to attempt to control the microbiome and put it in a "healthy state". You can indeed use consumption of some foods to shift microbiome composition. Presumably if you did this in a sufficiently disjointed way, you could throw your microbiome into a sort of ecological chaos.

However, it would be *much* simpler to just [constantly take antibiotics to ensure that your gut load of microbes was generally low](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fcimb.2019.00099/full). [This still isn't a good idea](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3466501/#:%7E:text=Moreover%2C%20recent%20studies%20have%20shown,immune%20responses%20in%20peripheral%20organs.), as it can lead to *Clostridium difficile* or *E. coli* infections or other bad things, but it would be a much more straightforward way of getting to the desired end state.